# What are the disadvantages of using large amount embedded resources in a .NET application?

Tags: .net, performance, embedded-resource

What are disadvantages using large amount embedded resources in a .NET application?

For example 500-2000 files, each 100KB? Loading time due to size immediately comes to mind but is there anything else?

Comment: Large [memory footrprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_footprint)

Comment: Realistically, the .NET memory space can only handle about 1.5 gig in a 32 bit environment. If your memory is going to be larger, you will need to compile specifically for 64-bit.